# zsh: Ambiguous completion only to file/directory names

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to have zsh supplement underscores when completing a file/directory name. That is to say,

```
$ ls mod_*
mod_sample
$ modsa<Press Tab>
# Here I want 'mod_sample' to appear as a candidate
```

I know that `zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _approximate` enables  ambiguous matching, but this applies to all kinds of completions (command, option, filename etc.). I want apply it only to file/directory name.

I tried `zstyle ':completion:path-files' completer _complete _approximate` and things like that, but didn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|?=_'
```

This tells the completion system that, for any character, it's allowed to insert a `_` to left of it.